# Unable to set CURLOPT_NOBODY without crashing curl_exec

Tags: php, curl

I've been killing myself all day for this one bug. I can't tell you enough how much I'd appreciate any possible help on this.

Basically, I have a very simple script. It logs into a website, looks at a file's header to see if it is an image type and then it downloads it. It then repeats this three times.

The problem here is that I cannot set CURLOPT_NOBODY without curl_exec crashing the entire script with -no- errors. (I can't even call or get an curl_error!)It would seem that it is impossible for me to go from CURLOPT_NOBODY, true to CURLOPT_NOBODY, false. The loop below runs one time and then dies().

What could possibly be causing this bug?

Here is the script:

```
// Log into the Website
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myexample.com/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.12) Gecko/2009070611 Firefox/3.0.12");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_exec($ch);

// Begin the Loop for Finding Images
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myexample.com/file.php?id=' . $i);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch) or die('WHY DOES THIS DIE!!!');
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo '<br/>' . $output;

    // (Normally checks for content type here) Download the File
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myexample.com/file.php?id=' . $i);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    $filename = 'downloads/test-' . $i . '.jpg';
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I'm running apache 2.2 and PHP version 5.2.13.
Thanks for any help- I can't tell you how much I'd appreciate it. I'm completely stuck here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the curl library is getting confused, esp when you are reusing the resource.

you should do

```
$ch = curl_init();
// do stuff with curl
curl_close($ch);
$ch = curl_init();
// another curl call
curl_close($ch);
$ch = curl_init();
// yet another curl call
curl_close($ch);
```

I was given the same errors executing your script, but adding in the curl_close's and the curl_init to reinitialize, seem to fix the problem.  I don't know if this is acceptable, if not.  I'd use the fopen() to do your http downloading, its much more intuitive than using curl, unless you need something that isn't supported in fopen.

Comment: I love you. I really do. Thank you SO much! This bug had absolutely ruined my week. I had thrown away hours and hours into trying to find out what was causing it with no luck, random outputs, and no error messages. Here I was using curl completely wrong! Know that you've made someone very, VERY happy here! Thanks again :)